# Ngx-Lightbox ASSERTION ERROR: token must be defined [Expected=> null != undefined <=Actual]

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 12.1.4 and trying to implement ngx-lightbox 2.0.0 using this documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-lightbox.

For reference following is the component.ts code:

```
  export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  public _albums: Array <{src:string,caption:string,thumb:string}>=[];
  constructor(public _lightbox: Lightbox) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
      const src = 'https://themyth92.com/project/ngx-lightbox/demo/img/image' + i + '.jpg';
      const caption = 'Image ' + i + ' caption here';
      const thumb = 'https://themyth92.com/project/ngx-lightbox/demo/img/image' + i + '-thumb.jpg';
      const album = {
         src: src,
         caption: caption,
         thumb: thumb
      };
      this._albums.push(album);
    }
  }
  open(index: number): void {
    this._lightbox.open(this._albums, index);
  }
  close(): void {
    this._lightbox.close();
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Following is my component.html code:

```
<div *ngFor="let image of _albums; let i=index">
    <img [src]="image.thumb" (click)="open(i)" />
</div>
```

I do see the image thumbnails on the screen without any console error but as soon as I click on the image, I get the following issue:

[image]

Comment: Do you found an answer?

Comment: Nop. Are you also facing same problem?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the packages? Worked for me